# Testing with enzyme got Cannot read property 'be' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My test

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import topNav from '../components/topNav';

it('Navbar should existed', () => {
  const Navbar = shallow(<topNav />);
  expect(Navbar.find('#topNav').exists()).to.be(true);

});
```

My topNav

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class topNav extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="topNav">Nav bar</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. I took the exact example from the API doc of enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in the name `topNav`, all `react` components must starts with uppercase letter, because name with small letters starting are treated as `HTML` elements, so instead of `topNav` use `TopNav`.

Check this one: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad